# Implementing Access Token in Tile Server?

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles, tile-server

I am using Tileserver-GL for rendering vector tiles to web and mobile. For web, I am using Mapbox JS API GL and for Mobile, I am using Mapbox android SDK. Currently, I am using flat URL given by Tileserver-GL like

```
http://1.1.1.1:8080/data/v3/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf
```

or for mobile use

```
mapView.setStyleUrl("http://1.1.1.1:8080/styles/bright/style.json");
```

but as you can see this URL is open and anyone can access it.

Since we are not using Mapbox Access Token, how can we protect our Url from public to abuse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://tileserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html)

> **Deployment**
>
> Typically - you should use nginx/lighttpd/apache on the frontend - and the tileserver-gl server is hidden behind it in production deployment.
>
> **Securing**
>
> Nginx can be used to add protection via https, password, referrer, IP address restriction, **access keys**, etc.